# Exchange with internal domain: how to make meeting requests work?

Tags: exchange, calendar

I have an exchange server with the domain internal.example.com

Outgoing e-mail goes through a mail gateway which rewrites addresses to example.com

Unfortunately calendar and meeting requests to external people are broken since they still show the internal.example.com domain. So we can't invite external people to meetings.

How can I fix this?

(I can't remove the mail gateway)

Answer (score 2):

Why are addresses being re-written? Exchange has no need to do this, I've not seen a gateway that requires this, and the obvious solution to your issue, that doesn't mean removing the gateway, is configuring the correct email addressing scheme in exchange and stop the gateway from re-writing email addresses.

Comment: Internally we have *lots* of sub-domains that decide where mail is routed to. For example myname@example.com is routed to myname@internal.example.com, but lots of e-mail is routed from e.g. something@example.com to something@somesubdomain.example.com

We mustn't break anything else but need to fix the calendaring issue.